# How to find largest number with arrays, in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, public

For this college assignment I am required to use `public static int indexOfLargestElement(double[] array)`.

```
public class FindLargest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

public static int indexOfLargestElement(double[] array) {
    return 0;
}
{
int numbers[] = new int[]{(int) 1.9,(int) 2.5,(int) 3.7,2,(int) 1.5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2};

    int largest1 = numbers[0];

    for(int i =1;i<numbers.length;i++) {
        int indexOfLargestElement;
            if(numbers[i] > largest1)
            largest1 = numbers[1];
        }
    }


    System.out.println("Largest Element Number is: " + largest1); 

    return.largest; 
}
```

Comment: Post the code that you've written so far.

Comment: Please hold on another computer.

Comment: Please note that on SO anyone is willing to help other people with real questions. But in this case and without any sample code it seems that the SO community shall do your college homework. So please post your code written so far as Eric Guan wrote before.

Comment: I apologize im new. I used Eclipse so, it made me change things around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double numbers []= {1.9,2.5,3.7,2,1.5,6,3,4,5,2};
    int index= indexOfLargestElement(numbers);
    System.out.println("The index of the largest number is: "+index);

}
public static int indexOfLargestElement(double[] array){
    int index=0;
    double largest=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i]>largest){
            largest= array[i];
            index=i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: when I try to compile, error.

Comment: *Update, your whole code should look like that, try to follow it, mi output was 
"The index of the largest number is: 5"

Comment: IT WORKED! thanks you are good people

Comment: Hey, one quick question, what would be the code if i wanted to enter the the ten numbers?

Comment: If you want the numbers to be static just add them in the array like {number,number2,...,numbern} or you could read them using the Scanner library, it has a method called nextInt() which accepts information from the console

Comment: if you wouldnt mind, can you do edit you answer with it. Thanks. you have been very helpful